# How to resize the height of today Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to resize the height of widget in iOS 11?

I cannot resize the height of today Extension.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded


}

func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact {
        //compact
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    } else {
        //extended
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write to the didReceiveMemoryWarning but the correct is to write to the viewDidLoad

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded}

func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact {
        //compact
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    } else {
        //extended
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 200)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a guess, but try this (using `maxSize.width` instead of 0 width):

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {

    if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact {
        //compact
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    } else {
        //extended
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add this line to enable `.expanded` mode (e.g., to `viewDidLoad`):

```
self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
```

Comment: I just tested it on iOS11 device, and it's working for me

Comment: Thanks! but I cannot resize the height of today Extension.

Comment: ```widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode``` was my missing link! :)